# type annotation in a vue3 template with a v-for loop

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

so lets assume i have declared a interface for Product like so

```
export interface Product {
  id: number;
  Name: string;
  Number: string;
}
```

and have a function to retrieve an array of products and I want to iterate over the array  to render a list of products like so

```
<Product
      v-for="product in products"
      :key="product.id"
      :product=product
    >
```

And this works just fine but for the sake of annotate this right, because now product in the v-for ins considered a string even typescript gets that products is a array of products, how do i get the product annotated so typescript stops complaining to me that product has no property id and prop product is not assignable to a string?

Again this is simply to get a way to annotate this so it will be recognized by typescript as a Product not a string. The code works just fine and renders!

**Update:**

the fetching of the products in the setup pf my productlist component

```
  async setup(_, context) {
    const { products } = await LoadProductList();
    return {
      products,
      context,
      Product,
    };
  },
```

because it will come up how i  fetch it here is the ts part

```
export async function LoadProductList() {
    const { response: products, request } = useApi<IProduct[]>(
      "http://mr-freebsd:5111/api/products"
    );
    const loaded = ref(false);
    if (loaded.value === false) {
      await request();
      loaded.value = true;
    }
    return { products };
  }
```

again the code is working fine i simply want a precompile typecheck to work properly which it doesnt do at the moment in tenplate part of the productlist with the code shown in the initial post.

cheers

Markus

Comment: Show how you declare `products` in your component.